# Selecting value in matrix together with column name in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix from which I would like to select an observation together with its column name.

If I use `subset()` or `matrix[]%in%` then I get the whole row.

I would only like to get that single observation and its column name.
Is there a way to do this?

Here's an example:

matrix:

```
        col1 col2 col3
row 1    10   20    30 
row 2    30   30    40
```

Now I would like to select the value and column name with the highest value:

```
max <- max(matrix)
subset(matrix, matrix==max)
```

This gives the output:

```
        col1 col2 col3
row 2    30   30    40
```

However what I would like to get is:

```
       col3
        40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know the value, you just need to get the column names.

Calling your matrix `m` for the obvious reason:

```
m <- matrix(c(10,30,20,30,30,40), ncol=3)
colnames(m) <- c('col1','col2','col3')
```

To see which columns contain the max (or any particular value), and their names, `apply` can be used to return a logical vector with names:

```
apply(m==10, 2, any)
col1  col2  col3 
TRUE FALSE FALSE 

apply(m==30, 2, any)
col1 col2 col3 
TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

`which` tells you which values are true:

```
which(apply(m==40, 2, any))
col3 
   3
```

And just the names, if that is what you need:

```
names(which(apply(m==40, 2, any)))
[1] "col3"
```

Comment: thanks for the help, yes I would need something to work in both cases when max>1 and when max=1.

Comment: In my case the max value can only occur in once in every column. so I would need something that selects multiple columns in case there is more than one max value

Comment: 2 means apply over column margins.  See ?apply.

Comment: but the which command doesn't seem to work: Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Comment: Parens out of place?  `which` takes no FUN argument, but `apply` does.

Comment: right sorry, but then it basically returns both the column name and the column number. is there some additional argument to have only one of them?

Comment: `names` will extract the names.  You can use the result of `which` as a column index (ignoring the fact that it has names) if you want the column number.

Comment: the final problem is that if I use which then it will only select 1 column but if m larger than 1 then it still selects only one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21566/discussion-between-matthew-lundberg-and-user1723765)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setNames(c(m), colnames(m)[col(m)])[m == max(m)]
```